# should I exclude sqlite-shm and sqlite-wal files with a Simperium-backed Core Data iOS app

Tags: simperium

I'm agnostic about the shm and wal files, which are included by default since iOS7. I'm just wondering if they in any way affect Simperium APIs. And if so, should I specifically [exclude](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-remove-wal-files-in-core-data/) those files when provisioning a sqlite db for the app. (Deployment Target for the app is 9.0.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simperium itself doesn't deal with Core Data internals. It should be safe to exclude the journaled files, since the framework only interacts with the framework via its Public API, and Journaled / Unjournaled storage is (as far as i know!) a private detail.

If anything, please, feel free to open an issue in the iOS GitHub repository, we'd be happy to help!:

https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios

Have a great day!
Jorge